# React redirect to another page with props

Tags: reactjs

I have a table with unique row id's. When I click on a row I use that id to redirect to a view. To do this I'm doing a simple `window.location.href = "url/view/" + id;` On my view page I'm grabbing the id set in the url with `id = this.props.match.params.id;` 
My view however has sub-menus that use routes to load different component and in doing so the id gets lost when I navigate to other components for obvious reasons. I need a way to send that id as props when I click on the table row.

This is my first React app and I'm struggling. Any help is appreciated.

My table (bootstrap table)

```
<BootStrapTable
  keyField="id"
  data={data}
  columns={columns}
  pagination={paginationFactory()}
  rowEvents={rowevent}
  {...props.baseProps}
/>
```

rowevent

```
const rowevent = {
  onClick: (e, row) => {
    console.log(row.id);
    window.location.href = "url/view/" + row.id;
  }
};
```

On my view page

```
render() {
const id = this.props.match.params.id;
return (
  <Container className="col-md-12">
    <Sidebar part={id} />
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/url/view/:id" exact component={View} />
            <Route path="/url/create" exact component={Add} />
            <Route
              path="/url/test"
              exact
              render={props => <Test {...props} test={id} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
  </Container>
);
```

I hope this makes it clear. In my view I have a sidebar and routers that load different components based on what I click on the sidebar. I'm not sure if this is the best way to do this. But when I click on an option on the sidebar for example `url/test` I pass the id with it to get some result. Now in the sidebar if I click on the navigation for `url/view/:id` again the id in the url is gone so it wont return back to the view. So I need to send id as a prop from the table click so it won't disappear.

Comment: Can you post the code you currently have?

Comment: @brycelikesdogs udpated above

Comment: Can you provide full related code include the handling in your `sub-menus` component?

Comment: So one solution would be to store the id in the react state instead and pass it down to components that need it. This way it wouldn't get lost when the url changes.

Comment: @brycelikesdogs I tried that but it doesn't satisfy what i wanted

Comment: In which ways was it unsatisfactory?

Comment: @keikai updated above

Comment: @JustinS Try to remove `exact`

Comment: @keikai I did, it didnt work. Right now the issue is if i click on the sidebar for "Tests" the url changes to ```url/test``` from ```url/view/id``` When that happens id that i grab with ```props.match.param.id``` becomes undefined

Comment: Because you are changing the url, you need to store the id somewhere else instead. Either in the react state or by using a state management library like Redux

Comment: @brycelikesdogs how do i send the state variable from the table click event to my view?